# User Friendly Name from system account, workgroup

Tags: delphi, winapi

My process (regular app, not a service. app is launched by service, not by user, but in user's session) runs under **SYSTEM account** (it's required by other reasons) in user's session(s). Is there any way to get current session's **user friendly name** if the PC is **in a workgroup**?

-getting desktop's ('Progrman') user as -GetTokenInformation - LookupAccountSid - and making a TranslateName does not give me the f.name () in a workgroup (as written in msdn, it works in a domain).

-GetUserNameExW does not give me f.name because my process works under SYSTEM account (GetUserNameExW retrieves the data for calling process's account)

So, is there any other way of **process-independent** user friendly name providing **for workgroups** ?

```
function GetUserNameEx(var AUserName: string; var AFriendlyUserName: string): Boolean;
var
  ProcessID: Integer;
  phToken, hProcess, hWindow: THandle;
  cbBuf: Cardinal;
  ptiUser: PTOKEN_USER;
  snu: SID_NAME_USE;
  szDomain, szUser : array [0..50] of Char;
  chDomain, chUser : Cardinal;

  UserName1: array[0..250] of Char;
  FriendlyUserName: array[0..250] of Char;
  Size: DWORD;

const
  NameUnknown = 0; // Unknown name type.
  NameFullyQualifiedDN = 1;  // Fully qualified distinguished name
  NameSamCompatible = 2; // Windows NT® 4.0 account name
  NameDisplay = 3;  // A "friendly" display name
  NameUniqueId = 6; // GUID string that the IIDFromString function returns
  NameCanonical = 7;  // Complete canonical name
  NameUserPrincipal = 8; // User principal name
  NameCanonicalEx = 9;
  NameServicePrincipal = 10;  // Generalized service principal name
  DNSDomainName = 11;  // DNS domain name, plus the user name

begin
  Result := False;
  AUserName := '';
  AFriendlyUserName := '';
  hWindow := FindWindow('Progman', 'Program Manager');
  if hWindow <> 0 then
  begin
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(hWindow, @ProcessID);
    hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);
    if hProcess <> 0 then
    begin
      if OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, phToken) then
      begin
        if not GetTokenInformation(phToken, TokenUser, nil, 0, cbBuf) then
          if GetLastError()<> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then exit;
        if cbBuf = 0 then exit;
        GetMem(ptiUser, cbBuf);
        try
          chDomain := 50;
          chUser   := 50;
          if GetTokenInformation(phToken, TokenUser, ptiUser, cbBuf, cbBuf) then
            if LookupAccountSid(nil, ptiUser.User.Sid, szUser, chUser, szDomain,
              chDomain, snu) then
              begin
                AUserName := szUser;
                Result := True;

                if Trim(szDomain) <> '' then
                begin
                  FillChar(UserName1, 251, 0);
                  FillChar(FriendlyUserName, 251, 0);
                  StrCopy(UserName1, PChar(Trim(szDomain) + '\' + Trim(szUser)));
                  Size := 251;
  //THIS CODE WORKS FOR DOMAINS ONLY, NOT FOR WORKGROUPS
                  if TranslateName(@UserName1, NameSamCompatible, NameDisplay, @FriendlyUserName, @Size) then
                    AFriendlyUserName := Trim(FriendlyUserName);
                end;
              end
            else
              raise Exception.Create('Error in GetTokenUser');
        finally
          FreeMem(ptiUser);
        end;
      end
      else begin
        AUserName := 'OpenProcessToken = False';
        Result := False;
      end
    end
    else begin
      AUserName := '';
      Result := False;
    end
  end
  else begin
    AUserName := '';
    Result := False;
  end
end;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean that you run under SYSTEM? Your process is a service? In which case the session is always session 0. Or are you using a non standard definition of the word session?

Comment: sorry, fixed that. it's a normal app that runs under system account in user's session(s), NOT a service in user session 0. This app is launched by service, not by user, but in user's session.

Comment: I think the solution should be the same as if it was a service that needs to get friendly names of currently logged in users (for pc in a workgroup)...

Comment: It sounds like a bad design to have a process in the user's session that runs with system privileges. Processes running as system should be in the services session. In a workgroup, there are only local accounts which only have a username and a description (optional) but not a displayname, given name etc as those are all attributes of the directory service (Active Directory)

Comment: unclear what concrete information you want get. may be `PolicyAccountDomainInformation` ?

Comment: and if you use localsystem token - you faster need use `WTSQueryUserToken` and query it. not self token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetUserNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435(v=vs.85).aspx) respects impersonation so you can call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` with your token to get information about the user.

However, in a workgroup environment only `NameSamCompatible` seems to work and everything else returns ERROR_NONE_MAPPED (The user name is not available in the specified format).

Calling `NetUserGetInfo` also just returns a empty string for `usri*_full_name`.

There is also a undocumented shell function to retrieve the display name but it just falls back to `GetUserName` when `GetUserNameEx` fails.

Comment: ImpersonateLoggedOnUser solved the issue, thank you!